# How to know the Dynamodb updateItem response status in AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running an update item statement to update a item in a table.
I'm accessing dynamoDB via AWS SDK for PHP. But at the end of the execution how do I know whether the particular update has been successfully completed. by looking at the returned results.

eg:-

```
$response = $client->updateItem(....)

//How do I do this properly
if($response == 'successfull'){
}
else{
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume success, unless an exception is thrown.

```
try {
    $result = $client->updateItem(...);
} catch (\Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException $e) {
    // handle error
}

// handle result
```

Here are more details from the [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html#detecting-and-handling-errors).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy. This is simple and very useful. Got it solved. Thanks again